# Segfault while inserting to binary tree

Tags: c, malloc, binary-tree

How to use pointers in inserting new node to binary tree when I have in my header struct:

```
typedef struct bst_node {
  char key;               
  int value;         
  struct bst_node *left; 
  struct bst_node *right; 
} bst_node_t;
```

How to allocate memory when I use double pointer in void parameters? When I try to run this in tests I get segfault

```
void bst_insert(bst_node_t **tree, char key, int value) {
  if(tree == NULL){
    tree = malloc(sizeof(struct bst_node));
    (*tree)->key = key;
    (*tree)->value = value;
    (*tree)->right = NULL;
    (*tree)->left =NULL;
  }
  else if(key == (*tree)->key){
    (*tree)->value = value;
  }
  else if((*tree)->key > key){
    bst_insert(&(*tree)->left, key, value);
  }else{
    bst_insert(&(*tree)->right, key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (tree == NULL){ tree = ...` is wrong. It should be `if (*tree == NULL) { *tree = ...`

Comment: yes but better to check both `tree` and `*tree`, more preferable IMO to use a single `*` and return a function value not `void`.

Comment: It can be a lot easier to write the code correctly if you start by converting the double pointer to a single pointer, e.g. `bst_node_t *node = *tree;`. Then all of the code can be written using `node` instead of `(*tree)`, making the code easier to read and understand. The one thing you have to remember is the line `*tree = node;` which updates the pointer that `tree` points to. In the given code, that's only needed in one place, at the end of the first `if` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function takes a pointer to a pointer to a `bst_node_t`. If `bst_insert` receives a `bst_node_t **tree` that is `NULL`, then there is nothing that function can do, because it cannot access the tree.

```
void bst_insert(bst_node_t **tree, char key, int value) {
  if(tree == NULL){
    return; //There is nothing to be done.
```

On the other hand, if the pointer that `tree` **points to** is `NULL`, then we have a valid reference to a tree structure that is empty, so we can allocate memory and store (a pointer to) it at the memory location that `tree` points to:

```
  if(*tree == NULL){
    *tree = malloc(sizeof(struct bst_node)); //What if malloc fails?
    (*tree)->key = key;
    (*tree)->value = value;
    (*tree)->right = NULL;
    (*tree)->left =NULL;
  }
```

The line in your original program that says `tree = malloc(...` is not only not what you want, it is a memory leak, because when `bst_insert` returns, that value will be lost and you will have no way to `free` the memory.

Since it is possible for this function to fail, like if you were to call `bst_insert(NULL, 0, 0);` it may be wise to change the return type from `void` to `int` so that `bst_insert` can communicate to its caller that it was unable to do its job.